# Excel: Pivot Table Does Not Filter

Tags: excel, filter, pivot, filtering, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet that has similar data to (except I have 256K rows):

```
Company $
A       10
A       20
A       30
B       20
B       30
C       40
C       60
D       10
D       0
D       10
```

I created a Pivot Table where the Rows are grouped by `Company` and the Values show the sum of `$`.

I am trying to have it filter for values where the `sum of $` is `>= 50`. So I go to Filter for `$` and do greater than or equal to 50

[image]

When I do this, nothing is changed. I know I can always manually select every value where the value is >= 50 but that would take a long time because my data has too many rows.

I tried adding a column in my data to return the sum of $ by comparing Company name (`=SUMIF(A:A,"="&A2,B:B)`)but that would take a very long time for 256K rows.

What am I doing wrong with my filtering? Why isn't it actually filtering based on value?

Comment: Do you want to filter before or after summing up the single values (i.e. in the base data or the pivot data)? If you want to filter afterwards, how exactly do you do that?

Comment: After. I want to filter on the sum of $ for a company.

Comment: I do not see an option to filter on an aggregate column of a pivot table (in my Excel 2007 at least). How do you do that? Copy and pasting as values and using an auto filter afterwards should work, though.

Comment: It works for me using your simple data set. Is the field you're filtering in the rightmost row field? That has made a difference for me in the past.

Comment: @Leviathan, in a non-value field, choose Filter and then Value Filter.

Comment: @Doug: Wow, that's counterintuitive - never would have thought of filtering in the "wrong" field. Thanks! I can now confirm that the filter works with the given data.

Comment: @Leviathan, I know what you mean. The thing is it matters which non-value field you filter the value field by, hence my earlier question to the poster. Which field you use changes the granularity, which isn't necessarily reflected in the values that are displayed. Or something like that... :-)

Comment: Im not sure I follow you @doug. How am I supposed to filter this.

Comment: I was curious which field you applied the value filter to. I'm also curious where that field is on your pivot table. If your pivot data really only consists of the two columns then you can ignore my question.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Your solution of filtering on a non-value field worked! If you post it as an answer Ill accept it :D

Comment: Bijan, I'd be happy to, but I'm not sure what fixed it. To clarify, you can only apply that filter to non-value fields. What I think happened is that you changed the filter from one non-value field, e.g., row field, to another. Is that what happened? If so, I'll answer accordingly. I think it's a really useful thing for people to know about.

Comment: I added a value filter for `Company` where `Sum of $` is `>=50`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112542/discussion-between-doug-glancy-and-bijan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for a good question.

The short answer that you need to apply the filter to a non-Value field, Company in this case. If you filter on the Value field itself nothing happens (something I didn't even know you could do until you showed me.)

The only other thing I'd note on this topic is that it matters which non-Value field you pick. For instance if you'd had a Region field and applied the filter to that it also might have no effect if all the regions subtotal to more than 50. This seems obvious, but since that whole thing is rather unintuitive it's probably worth pointing out.

For a really good explanation of Value Filters, see [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/465157/33661).